# Shaking css transition in Safari and Chrome

Tags: jquery, css

I am making a transition, combining a width-transition and rotate-transition. 
http://innouveau.nl/loodsboot-wp/test/index2.html

The problem is, that in Safari and Chrome, the transition is very shaky.

As you see, during the transition a scrollbar appears, I guess this has something to do with it. When I set the parent to overflow:hidden, the scrollbar is invisible, but the shake is still there:
http://www.innouveau.nl/loodsboot-wp/test/index1.html

When the transition is only on the rotate, there is no shake:
see "index3.html" (sorry not allowed to post 3 links yet)

I am using jquery.transit lib but the shake is also there using the normal css-way.

Comment: have you tried to do the transition on the 'img' itself, rather than it's parent of parent of parent div?

Comment: would you like the div#rondleiding to remain the same size? if so you can give it a fixed width, change it position relative, and than div#rondleiding-img-frame to position absolute..

Comment: My final thing will look like this
http://www.innouveau.nl/loodsboot-wp/
Every part of the drawing is a seperate img, so the img itself cannot rotate.
The #rondleiding remains the same size, although its supposed to be responsive, so actually not...
Why so? You think it has to do with relative positioning?

Comment: I see, have you tried to animate scale() instead of width?

Comment: no net yet, will try later this day, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are making your width twice the size.. my solution is to animate on scale instead:

start position:

```
 $(.draggable).css({'-webkit-transform': 'rotate(0deg) scale(1) translate(0,0)'});
```

end position:

```
$(.draggable).css({'-webkit-transform': 'rotate(-90deg) scale(2) translate(0,-200px)'});
```

here's a [test demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GAUqV/)

let me know if it works out :)

Comment: thanks. it works, but... when I add 'left' it is shaking again...
http://jsfiddle.net/GAUqV/15/

Comment: maybe try using translate instead of left.. look at the answer update and this http://jsfiddle.net/GAUqV/17/

Comment: Couldnt see the jsfiddle since there server is down, but I tried the translate and it worked just fine! thanks a million.
You have any idea why this is working and the other thing doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent appearing of scroll bar without using overflow you can set this:

```
#right{
  min-height: 750px;
}
```

Comment: Using overlow isnt the problem, I just left it out, so you can see a scrollbar appears. The appearing of the scroll bar isnt the problem itself, I think its has something to do with the shaking.